# Vue: Make sure the component cannot modify props (even if it is a reference object)?

Tags: vue.js

I know that the vue model is a unidirectional data flow of props.

However, when prop is a reference object, the component can directly modify its properties. This is wrong, but vue will not check it.

I hope there is a mechanism to ensure that the component cannot modify the props (even if it is a reference object), rather than being checked by the developer.

For example, I have a component

```
<template>
  <input v-model="obj.text" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['obj']
};
</script>
```

And a page that uses it

```
<template>
  <my-template :obj="myobj"></my-template>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    myobj: {
      text: "hello";
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

When data changes in 'input', myobj.text will change together. This violates the unidirectional data flow.

Of course, as shown in the answer, I can use the "get" and "set" methods of the "computed".

But I must be careful not to write 'obj.someProperty' to any 'v-model', but this requires my own attention.

I hope there is a mechanism to give a hint when I make a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find an existing duplicate so here's an answer. If anyone can find one, let me know and I'll make this one a *Community wiki*.

---

Use a computed property with *getter* and *setter* to represent your `v-model` value.

The *getter* gets the value from the prop and the *setter* emits the new value to the parent.

For example

```html
<input v-model="computedProp">
```

```js
props: ['referenceObject'],
computed: {
  computedProp: {
    get () {
      return this.referenceObject.someProperty
    },
    set (val) {
      this.$emit('updated', val)
    }
  }
}
```

and in the parent

```html
<SomeComponent :reference-object="refObject" @updated="updateRefObject">
```

```js
data: () => ({ refObject: { someProperty: 'initial value' } }),
methods: {
  updateRefObject (newVal) {
    this.refObject.someProperty = newVal
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is not what I want.
I want a way to ensure that the "referenceObject" (and its 'property') passed in as props are not modifiable in the component. Instead of creating a calculated attribute.
If I accidentally use referenceObject.someProperty as the "v-model" in the component, I can modify it.
Of course, I can construct a calculated property (such as calculatedProp in your example), but this requires my own attention. Write "calculatedProp" instead of "referenceObject" in the v-model.
I hope there is a mechanism to give a hint when I make a mistake.